# How do get stdDeviation in SVG to be responsive?

Tags: svg

I use the following SVG filter to round the corners of my clip-path path:

```
<svg style="visibility: hidden;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="round">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

The result:

[image: On low resulution (HD)]

The problem, here is the same result on much higher resolution:
[image: Result on much higher resolution (5K)]

How do I make the stdDeviation="15" part of the code responsive, so that the edges will be rounded by the same amount, indifferent of the resolution?

My site / divs dimensions are set in vw units, if that matters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the blur using objectBoundingBox units. Like so:

```
    <svg style="visibility: hidden;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="round" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation=".02" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!

Comment: There is an other issue, if you observe the left and right sides of the brown div to which the clip path is applied, there is a "margin" of about 1 pixel on both sides (there's no margin defined, all widths are set to 100%), and it's caused by the filter. Could you suggest any fix for that issue? It's only visible on the first screenshot, which is the low resolution screenshot.

Comment: The filter clips off the margins of the div on both left and right sides, about 1 px width on each sides. The filter is applied to the parent of the actual clipped element, hence it has effect on the child. But both parent and child are set to 100% width, so why does the filter clips off about 1 px on each sides?

Comment: So I didn't find the solution but I added this CSS to the div that has the filter applied, and it's solved: position: relative; min-width: 100.2vw; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);